# openstack compute node not registering

Tags: linux, openstack, openstack-nova, centos9

I am trying to manually install `Openstack Yoga` in virtual environment (Rocky Linux 9). I am struggling to bring my `compute node` in the * Openstack hypervisor list*. Following [this guide](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/yoga/install/) to install Openstack yoga.

I have carefully followed the instructions many times and have watched many videos on youtube too, but, no luck. I will really appreciate if someone can assist. Don't want to give up.

`compute1` host shows up as the `compute host` in the Horizon and with the following command, however, there is nothing listed under the `hypervisor list`.

```
[root@controller ~]# openstack compute service list
+--------------------------------------+----------------+------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
| ID                                   | Binary         | Host       | Zone     | Status  | State | Updated At                 |
+--------------------------------------+----------------+------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
| bce48397-8111-49fe-9b05-9cdd4d24a229 | nova-scheduler | controller | internal | enabled | up    | 2022-12-30T06:20:05.000000 |
| c4a75344-88d4-4cc2-b63a-7e1820069dbd | nova-conductor | controller | internal | enabled | up    | 2022-12-30T06:20:05.000000 |
| 30f7698f-a684-4b1d-9eed-351d587b32c4 | nova-compute   | compute1   | nova     | enabled | up    | 2022-12-30T06:19:57.000000 |
+--------------------------------------+----------------+------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
```

`[root@controller ~]# openstack hypervisor list` #returns nothing.

```
 [root@controller ~]# nova-status upgrade check
    
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Upgrade Check Results                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Check: Cells v2                                                    |
| Result: Success                                                    |
| Details: No host mappings or compute nodes were found. Remember to |
|   run command 'nova-manage cell_v2 discover_hosts' when new        |
|   compute hosts are deployed.                                      |
```

**When trying to discover the nodes, getting the following message**

```
[root@controller ~]# su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 discover_hosts --verbose" nova
Found 2 cell mappings.
Skipping cell0 since it does not contain hosts.
Getting computes from cell 'cell1': fe28e42c-493f-48e5-956d-9f5494a99df6
Found 0 unmapped computes in cell: fe28e42c-493f-48e5-956d-9f5494a99df6
```

Am I missing something? Should I install any additional packages, which are not listed in the guide?

**Compute Node Nova Configuration**
https://pastebin.com/6dhkCeW0

Comment: Can you add the output of `nova-manage cell_v2 list_cells` and `nova-manage cell_v2 list_hosts` to your question as well?